# AIX diff not showing the content of a new file

Tags: aix, diff

I need to create a patch between 2 folder:
On linux:
diff -Naur folder folder_fix

It's working for all the file I just edited but not for the one I added (can't get the content of it).

The command return:

```
Only in folder_fix/add/: file.conf
```

I need to get the content of that file on my file.patch

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can install GNU diffutils on AIX if you prefer. Or git for git diff.